# Swift beta 6 - Confusing linker error message

Tags: swift, xcode6

I'm getting an error message from the linker when building a Swift program with Xcode 6 beta 6, targeting iOS 8.  This code compiled and ran correctly with beta 5.

```
Undefined symbol for architecture x86_64:
__TFSs26_forceBridgeFromObjectiveCU__FTPSs9AnyObject_MQ__Q_", referenced from:
 __TFC8RayTrace14RayTracingPlot15drawFocalPointfS0_FT_T_ in RayTracingPlot.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

Here's the code in question:

```
private func drawFocalPoint() {
    var attributes = Dictionary<String, AnyObject>()

    let FString: String = "F"
    let distance: CGFloat = focalDistance

    let centerX = CGRectGetMidX(bounds)
    let centerY = CGRectGetMidY(bounds)

    let circleRadius: CGFloat = 4.0
    let focalPointFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, circleRadius * 2.0, circleRadius * 2.0)
    var path = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: focalPointFrame)
    let color = UIColor.blackColor()

    let currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    CGContextSaveGState(currentContext)
    let shadowColor = UIColor(white:0, alpha:0.75).CGColor
    CGContextSetShadowWithColor(currentContext, CGSizeMake(0, 4), CGFloat(8), shadowColor)

    // Image F
    var imageFPath = UIBezierPath(CGPath: path.CGPath)
    let imageFTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation((centerX - distance - circleRadius),
        (centerY - circleRadius))
    imageFPath.applyTransform(imageFTransform)
    color.set()
    imageFPath.fill()
    FString.drawAtPoint(CGPointMake(centerX - distance - circleRadius, centerY + 5), withAttributes:attributes)

    CGContextSetShadowWithColor(currentContext, CGSizeMake(0.0, 0.0), CGFloat(0.0), nil) // Clear shadow
    CGContextRestoreGState(currentContext)
}
```

I'd appreciate a hint about where in this code to look for the error so I can fix it.  Thank you.

Comment: Note: Beta6 has been pulled by Apple.

Comment: That might explain it. Thanks.

Comment: Better try a full clean (CMD+SHFT+OPT+K) and build anyway.

Comment: Beta 6 seems to be back up now and I just had this same error. Building on beta 5 and then building on beta 6 afterwards seemed to fix the issue.

Comment: Also getting this plus two others.. i hope this is just a bug

Comment: Try holding down the `Option Key` and going to `Product -> Clean Build Folder`.

Comment: Thanks, everybody. I'm reloading Xcode 6 now and I'll give these suggestions a try.

Comment: A similar thing is happening in beta 7, except it seems that deleting the Derived Data is not solving the issue. Any ideas?

Comment: This is known bug: http://www.openradar.appspot.com/17597453

Answer (score 118, accepted):

I got this error even with the new version of Beta6 that was release hours after the bad one got pulled.

I've solved this and other similarly illegible errors by deleting the contents of the Derived folder. You can find where that folder is located by going to Preferences > Locations.

The default path is:
/Users/[your username]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData

You can also hold `Option` while the Product menu is open in Xcode, which will change `Clean` to `Clean Build Folder`... and accomplish the same task without having to folder-hunt.

Comment: alright. Deleting the build directory did it. Couldn't just Cmd+K to clean it. Had to manually delete it.

Comment: You can also hold `Option` while the `Product` menu is open in Xcode, which will change `Clean` to `Clean Build Folder...` and accomplish the same task without having to folder-hunt.

Comment: You can also just use the "Delete" button in the Derived Data section of the project in the Organizer (`Window->Organizer->Projects-><Your Project>->Derived Data`)

Answer (score 7):

Another cause of this error (seen with Xcode 6.1.1, and Xcode 6.2 Beta 3), is having an enum with only one case in one class, and declaring a variable of that type in a second class.

This code will cause a linker error:

```
class ClassA {
    enum ExampleEnum {
        case Option1
    }
}

class ClassB {
    var example: ClassA.ExampleEnum = .Option1
}
```

This will fix it.

```
class ClassA {
    enum ExampleEnum {
        case Option1
        case Option2 // Added a second case
    }
}

class ClassB {
    var example: ClassA.ExampleEnum = .Option1
}
```

Radar for more info and a sample project: http://openradar.appspot.com/19369147

An enum with only one case is pretty useless in practice and so the compiler is probably optimizing it away or something. I hit this when setting up a new project, using an enum for achievements to be determined later, and had just 1 placeholder.

Also note: Use Watchdog http://watchdogforxcode.com/ to avoid having to worry about Derived Data issues.

Comment: Unbelievable. This was absolutely my problem. I wish I could give you multiple upvotes because of how hosed I would have been without this answer.

Comment: I'm so glad this answer caught the corner of my eye. This was my problem. Truly unbelievable. Thanks for posting this!

Answer (score 1):

For other people that might stumble on this error. I have had this when implementing `CocoaPods` and not setting my target's `Other Linker Flags` to `$(inherited)`