# Suddenly getting compiler crash "arrayForceCast" in Swift XCode beta 6

Tags: swift

After upgrading to xcode beta 6, the compile is suddenly exploding cryptically on me.  I get no inline messages of any kind, just this error in the build log.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "__TFSs15_arrayForceCastU___FGSaQ__GSaQ0__", referenced from:
      __TFC9MyProj6NavBar5stackfS0_FCSo20CDVInvokedUrlCommandT_ in NavBar.o
```

I managed to trace it down to this line of code, which worked fine on beta 5.

```
// A dictionary of String keys and arrays of NavBarItem instances as values.
var stacks: [String:[NavBarItem]] = [:]

func stack(cmd: CDVInvokedUrlCommand) {
    let stackName: String = cmd.arguments[0] as String

    if let stack = stacks[stackName] {

        // When I comment this line out I get a clean compile.
        navBar.setItems(stack, animated: false)

    }
}
```

My only guess is that it doesn't like be converting from a swift array to an `NSArray` somehow. Any ideas?

Comment: I'd be careful using beta 6, it was pulled as a "bad build".

Comment: Beta6 was pulled by Apple and is no longer available for download.  Seems that it had quite a few bugs still and may have been accidentally released.

Comment: Well that explains a lot! I just thought there had not been a beta release for a while and checked out the website, saw something new and gave it a download. Whoops.

Comment: There is a new version up there now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Swift beta 6 - Confusing linker error message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25371556/swift-beta-6-confusing-linker-error-message)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Launch Organizer and then hit the Delete button as shown below.  Rebuild and the error will go away.

[image]

Answer (score 63):

I got this error even with the new version of Beta6 that was release hours after the bad one got pulled.

There are some significant changes in Beta 6 and looks like Xcode is getting confused. A full clean didn't work either.

I've solved this and other similarly illegible errors by deleting the contents of the Derived folder. You can find where that folder is located by going to Preferences > Locations.

The default path is: /Users/[your username]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData

Comment: You can also clear derived data right from the Organizer: Choose the "Projects" tab for each project there's a handy "delete" button in the "Derived Data" section. That fixed this issue for me without needing to go digging around in the Library by hand.

Comment: you can also use the "Clean Build Folder" menu option to trash the derived data. It's not in the menu by default, but it's CMD+OPT+SHIFT+K (or just type clean in the help menu)

Comment: Sometimes (I don't know why) CMD + OPT + SHIFT + K is not available (also when opening the "Product" menu and holding OPT key). To add a little: in my case it wasn't enough just to delete the contents of "Derived Data". Cleaning the build directory manually in finder seemed to work. So perhaps this has to be done, too.

Answer (score 1):

I had the error.
Sometimes Xcode has such problems.
But with the app 'Watchdog' (available in the App Store), it did never happen again.

So Watchdog also solved this error for me. *I think it did the same as @Paul Ardeleanu did manually.*

[Link to Mac App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/watchdog-for-xcode/id734258109?mt=12)