# Xcode beta 6 errors

Tags: xcode, compiler-errors, beta

To anyone who is having similar issues in Bata 6. I solved it by deleting the content in /Users/[your username]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData as can be seen in this  post [Suddenly getting compiler crash "arrayForceCast" in Swift XCode beta 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25373437/suddenly-getting-compiler-crash-arrayforcecast-in-swift-xcode-beta-6)

Original post:

I just installed Xcode beta 6 and am getting very unusual errors. I cannot figure out what they are.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
"__TFSsoi1oUSs17_RawOptionSetType_USs21BitwiseOperationsTypeSs9Equatable__FTQ_Q__Q_",   referenced from:
  __TFC9CoolSpots29ProfileSettingsViewController13turnOnOffPushfS0_FCSo8UISwitchT_ in ProfileSettingsViewController.o
  __TFC9CoolSpots11AppDelegate11applicationfS0_FTCSo13UIApplication29didFinishLaunchingWithOptionsGSqCSo12NSDictionary__Sb in AppDelegate.o
"__TFSs15_arrayForceCastU___FGSaQ__GSaQ0__", referenced from:
  __TFC9CoolSpots8LocationcfMS0_FT6objectCSo8PFObject_S0_ in Location.o
  __TFC9CoolSpots19ShareViewController7mapViewfS0_FTGSQCSo9MKMapView_21didAddAnnotationViewsGSQGSaPSs9AnyObject____T_ in ShareViewController.o
  __TFC9CoolSpots23LoginMenuViewController7FBLoginfS0_FT_T_ in LoginMenuViewController.o
  __TFC9CoolSpots21ProfileViewController7mapViewfS0_FTGSQCSo9MKMapView_21didAddAnnotationViewsGSQGSaPSs9AnyObject____T_ in ProfileViewController.o
  __TFFC9CoolSpots21ProfileViewController11viewDidLoadFS0_FT_T_U_FTGSqGSaPSs9AnyObject___GSqCSo7NSError__T_ in ProfileViewController.o
  __TFFFC9CoolSpots21ProfileViewController11viewDidLoadFS0_FT_T_U_FTGSqGSaPSs9AnyObject___GSqCSo7NSError__T_U0_FTGSqGSaPS1____GSqS2___T_ in ProfileViewController.o
  __TFFFC9CoolSpots21ProfileViewController11viewDidLoadFS0_FT_T_U0_FTGSqCSo8PFObject_GSqCSo7NSError__T_U0_FTGSqGSaPSs9AnyObject___GSqS2___T_ in ProfileViewController.o
  ...
"__TFSs26_forceBridgeFromObjectiveCU__FTPSs9AnyObject_MQ__Q_", referenced from:
  __TFC9CoolSpots8LocationcfMS0_FT11coordinatesVSC22CLLocationCoordinate2D15relatedActivityCSo7NSArray8objectIdSS7addressSS_S0_ in Location.o
  __TFC9CoolSpots8LocationcfMS0_FT6objectCSo8PFObject_S0_ in Location.o
  __TFC9CoolSpots19ShareViewController14viewWillAppearfS0_FSbT_ in ShareViewController.o
  __TFC9CoolSpots19ShareViewController15prepareForSeguefS0_FTGSQCSo17UIStoryboardSegue_6senderGSQPSs9AnyObject___T_ in ShareViewController.o
  __TFC9CoolSpots19ShareViewController21cameraViewTookPicturefS0_FCSo7UIImageT_ in ShareViewController.o
  __TFFC9CoolSpots19ShareViewController14reverseGeocodeFS0_FGSqCSo10CLLocation_T_U_FTGSQGSaPSs9AnyObject___GSQCSo7NSError__T_ in ShareViewController.o
  __TFC9CoolSpots27ActivityTableViewController11viewDidLoadfS0_FT_T_ in ActivityTableViewController.o
  ...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: It means that certain symbols (code) aren't getting built for the arm64 architecture. You are probably targeting a 64-bit device. Try instead building for the simulator to see if you have the same problem.

Comment: If there is a question in here, I can't find it. If this is a suggestion to others, it should be an answer to an existing question or it just doesn't belong on SO.

Answer (score 14):

Yes! I too was completely confused by these errors.

Then I remembered to delete the "DerivedData" for the project (or as I did, the entire folder), found here:

~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData

(with thanks to @drmarvelous)

Comment: +1 BTW, if you go to "Settings" in the Xcode "Preferences" and tap on the "Locations" tab, there's a little arrow link next to the "Derived Data" settings that will take you directly to this folder. It saves you from having to remember this cryptic path.

Comment: I'm seeing this problem show up in beta 7 except none of the proposed solutions are working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 8):

Had the same strange errors after upgrading to xcode 6 beta 6. For me the problem got fixed with a `Product -> Clean`. And if that does not fix the errors hold down option key and click again on `Product` in the Menubar then you will see in the dropdown menu `Clean Build Folder...` click on that.

Comment: Or just use [Watchdog](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/watchdog-for-xcode/id734258109?mt=12) app. This little helper automatically cleans your xcode projects.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but deleting the "DerivedData" folder alone didn't work for me.  I had to change the Build Location to "Unique" in the advanced section of Locations.  I believe that this might be because I had to quarantine xcode to get it open using the command:

```
sudo xattr -dr com.apple.quarantine /Applications/Xcode6-Beta6.app
```

But I'm not sure about that.

Comment: Did you exit Xcode before deleting this derived data folder? Whenever Xcode gets a little weird, I go through this derived data folder dance, and it fixes it, so I'm surprised you had to go to these lengths. But I'm glad you solved your problem.