# Can't get SequenceType to work in Swift Beta 6

Tags: xcode, swift, xcode6-beta6

In beta 5 this code works perfectly, but it doesn't compile in Beta 6. Any ideas why?

```
struct GenericGenerator<T>: GeneratorType {
    var items: [T]
    mutating func next() -> T? {
        return items.isEmpty ? .None : items.removeAtIndex(0)
    }
}

class ExerciseContainer : SequenceType {

    var exercises: [Exercise] = []

    func generate() -> GenericGenerator<Exercise> {
        return GenericGenerator(items: self.exercises)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Suddenly getting compiler crash "arrayForceCast" in Swift XCode beta 6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25373437/suddenly-getting-compiler-crash-arrayforcecast-in-swift-xcode-beta-6)

Comment: CMD+OPT+SHIFT+K "Clean Build Folder" - helped. Thanks