# Can symbols for a single method in foundation framework be undefined?

Tags: xcode, macos, swift, foundation, nsbundle

In my Cocoa application written in Swift (Xcode 6 Beta 6 on OS X Mavericks) I would like to use a bundle resource. Is does not use any external libraries but only the `WebKit.framework`. I encountered an odd linker problem with the code I wrote and could reduce it to the second line in this snippet:

```
var bundle = NSBundle.mainBundle()

// Leads to linker error!
var path = bundle.pathForResource(resource, ofType: "js")
```

If I comment out the `pathForResource` line it compiles and runs fine. Otherwise it causes the build to fail. That is the output in where Xcode shows the error:

```
Ld /Users/Peter/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/OFrame-cyxuoheofsrztibvnaxacjxvlzsl/Build/Products/Debug/OFrame.app/Contents/MacOS/OFrame normal x86_64
    cd /Users/Peter/Projekte/OFrame
    export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.9
    /Applications/Xcode6-Beta6.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode6-Beta6.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk -L/Users/Peter/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/OFrame-cyxuoheofsrztibvnaxacjxvlzsl/Build/Products/Debug -F/Users/Peter/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/OFrame-cyxuoheofsrztibvnaxacjxvlzsl/Build/Products/Debug -filelist /Users/Peter/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/OFrame-cyxuoheofsrztibvnaxacjxvlzsl/Build/Intermediates/OFrame.build/Debug/OFrame.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/OFrame.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/../Frameworks -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -lswiftCore -L/Applications/Xcode6-Beta6.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/macosx -Xlinker -force_load -Xlinker /Applications/Xcode6-Beta6.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/arc/libarclite_macosx.a -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/Peter/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/OFrame-cyxuoheofsrztibvnaxacjxvlzsl/Build/Intermediates/OFrame.build/Debug/OFrame.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/OFrame.swiftmodule -framework WebKit -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/Peter/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/OFrame-cyxuoheofsrztibvnaxacjxvlzsl/Build/Intermediates/OFrame.build/Debug/OFrame.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/OFrame_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/Peter/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/OFrame-cyxuoheofsrztibvnaxacjxvlzsl/Build/Products/Debug/OFrame.app/Contents/MacOS/OFrame    

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "__TFSs26_forceBridgeFromObjectiveCU__FTPSs9AnyObject_MQ__Q_", referenced from:
      __TFC6OFrame15FrameController16injectJavaScriptfS0_FCSo8NSStringT_ in FrameController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I read about architecture problems with frameworks but they all were related to the framework as a whole. Not the use of single method. This leaves me puzzled. Even more irritating is that `NSBundle.pathForResource`is a class method in the foundation framework. Is there kind of a cache for built objects which I eventually need to purge?

I feel cursed. Whenever I try to do something with Xcode I encounter the strangest problems.

Answer (score 0):

After finding [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25371556/swift-beta-6-confusing-linker-error-message) shortly after posting mine, I found out that compiling with Xcode 6 Beta 5 worked. I purged the contents of the derived data folder, too. Now it compiles fine in Xcode 6 Beta 6, too.