# Swift - iOS - XCode 6.1 dyld fatal error symbol not found when referencing string literal

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

After updating Xcode to Version 6.1 (6A1052d), app keeps on crashing on iPhone 5s (iOS8.1). However, everything runs perfectly fine on XCode. The phone is never Jailbroken

```
Dyld Error Message:
  Symbol not found: __TFE10FoundationCSo8NSStringCfMS0_FT13stringLiteralVSs12StaticString_S0_
  Referenced from: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/5BBECE8A-1A62-44A7-90A2-24B9D295F471/Wikasa.app/Wikasa
  Expected in: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/5BBECE8A-1A62-44A7-90A2-24B9D295F471/Wikasa.app/Frameworks/libswiftFoundation.dylib
  Dyld Version: 353.5
```

Error happens on the following part (AppDelegate.swift file)

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

var firebaseURL: NSString! = "https://our-url.firebaseio.com" // Breakpoint: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_ARM_BREAKPOINT, subcode=0xe7ffdefe)

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary?) -> Bool {

    self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
}
```

The breakpoint is at "var firebaseURL" line. I tried removing it and it breaks on every string literal assigned to variable. I tried making the variable optional and unwrapped and it does not work, as well as trying both String and NSString.

The following is a more detailed version of crash log

```
Incident Identifier: 3434A3AD-F265-4488-8E4C-D89F7C85ABA0
CrashReporter Key:   833ec60342fb35c4d7bd633966af6b495301776b
Hardware Model:      iPhone5,2
Process:             Wikasa [1147]
Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/5BBECE8A-1A62-44A7-90A2-24B9D295F471/Wikasa.app/Wikasa
Identifier:          com.wikasa.Wikasa
Version:              (1.0)
Code Type:           ARM (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2014-10-24 14:28:35.931 +0700
Launch Time:         2014-10-24 14:23:22.137 +0700
OS Version:          iOS 8.1 (12B411)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x00000000e7ffdefe
Triggered by Thread:  0

Dyld Error Message:
  Symbol not found: __TFE10FoundationCSo8NSStringCfMS0_FT13stringLiteralVSs12StaticString_S0_
  Referenced from: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/5BBECE8A-1A62-44A7-90A2-24B9D295F471/Wikasa.app/Wikasa
  Expected in: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/5BBECE8A-1A62-44A7-90A2-24B9D295F471/Wikasa.app/Frameworks/libswiftFoundation.dylib
  Dyld Version: 353.5
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Indeed you are right, problem Solved, thanks Martin!!!

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, apparently a duplicate of [Swift beta 6 - Confusing linker error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25371556/swift-beta-6-confusing-linker-error-message) , credits to [Martin R](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1187415/martin-r_) for finding this!