# Strange Swift XCode 'Undefined Symbols' errors

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6

I was using Xcode 6.2 to compile some swift code for an extension target. I kept getting errors similar to:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "__TFSSCfMSSFT21_builtinStringLiteralBp8byteSizeBw7isASCIIBi1__SS", referenced from:
      __TFC23Hall_WatchKit_Extension16GlanceControllercfMS0_FT_S0_ in GlanceController.o
```

If I declared some properties it compiled fine, but as soon as I tried to use a string literal I begin getting these errors, so even code as simple as this would cause errors:

```
class GlanceController: WKInterfaceController {
    var service = "somestring"
}
```

I updated to XCode 6.3 and now, even in a completely empty implementation I get some errors like this:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "__TFSsoi1aUSs17_RawOptionSetType_USs21BitwiseOperationsTypeSs9Equatable__FTQ_Q__Q_", referenced from:
      __TTWVSC26NSKeyValueObservingOptionsSs21BitwiseOperationsType10FoundationFS0_oi1aUS0___fMQPS0_FTS2_S2__S2_ in GlanceController.o
```

I've tried all of the recommendations in this thread: [Swift beta 6 - Confusing linker error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25371556/swift-beta-6-confusing-linker-error-message)
but nothing helped.

Comment: Xcode 6.3 β2 (6D532l) is giving me mountains of these errors trying to build a newly created clean project!

Comment: Happens in previous β1 too.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the "Target Membership" of your files are appropriate.

Comment: This is happening to me even if I create a brand new Swift project and try to run it without even writing any new code in it.

Comment: I recommend you to download Xcode 6.1.1 latest build. I guess you have downloaded Xcode 6.3 beta version. Also update your OS to Yosemite if you have not already.

Answer (score 0):

I found clearing Xcode's `DerivedData` cache fixed this issue for me (despite Product > Clean not helping).

After quitting Xcode, navigate to `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` and delete the cache folder for your project. You can even delete the entire `DerivedData` folder, it will be rebuilt for each project when you reopen them.

Reopen Xcode, wait for it to reindex files to its heart's content, then build.

Comment: Did this help even with your newly created project you were having this issue with? I'm seeing the same thing, even after clearing the entire folder out.

Comment: Yes. It sounds like my issue is quite possibly caused by something else but manifesting the same errors.